# how to automatically add files to a visual studio project in a pre-compile step?

Tags: visual-studio, build-process, build-automation

I have a perl script to copy some files into my project directory . The pre-compile step of our project will run the script. But the problem is that copied files are not add to the project dependency automatically . Is there a way to add them by automation ?

Answer (score 1):

The copying and running of the scripts can be done by using the Pre Build and Post Build macros. Also the DTE provides things such as BuildEvents. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.buildevents_events%28ja-jp%29.aspx).